# How to call these kind of webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, soap

I am working on an app that consuming the below type of `Web Service`,can anybody help me how to call this `Web Service` and get the data from it? Please check the below base url for the `webservice`,

**url**

```
http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants

request format:

{"APIUserName" : "admin" , "Password" : "######"}
```

I want to consuming this `web service` but having no idea regarding this kind of `web service`, So can anybody help me to call this webservice?

Please.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) and try it out

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to retrieve data from a web service using Higher-Level Client Libraries example `OKhttp`,`Volley` or `Retrofit` , for your case i think that you can parse `XML` File or `JSON` File and get data to your app.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a method like this should work :)

```
public void postData(String un, String pw) {
    //Create request
    String mynamespace = "http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc";
    String methodName = "GetContestants";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(mynamespace, methodName);
    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo username = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    username.setName("APIUserName");
    //Set Value
    username.setValue(un);
    //Set dataType
    username.setType(String.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(username);

    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo password = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    password.setName("Password");
    //Set Value
    password.setValue(pw);
    //Set dataType
    password.setType(String.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(password);

    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; //if .NET server
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    String url = "http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants";
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        String soapAction = "http://www.fansplay.com/wsfptb20/FBS.svc/GetContestants";
        androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //log result to console
        Log.d("myapp", response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

disclaimer: more at this link: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-example/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of json parsing....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    sendRequest();
}

public void sendRequest() {
    String url=getString(R.string.str_url_json);
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,this,this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    textView.setText(error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    int userId,id;
    String title;
    String body;
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    GsonObjects gsonObjects[]=gson.fromJson(response, GsonObjects[].class);
    for(int i=0;i<gsonObjects.length;i++) {
        id = gsonObjects[i].getId();
        userId = gsonObjects[i].getUserId();
        title = gsonObjects[i].getTitle();
        body = gsonObjects[i].getBody();
        listUserId.add(String.valueOf(userId));
        listId.add(String.valueOf(id));
        listTitle.add(title);
        listBody.add(body);
    }    

}
```

There is an model class:

```
public class GsonObjects implements Serializable {
@SerializedName(Constant.JSON_USER_ID)
private int userId;
@SerializedName(Constant.JSON_ID)
private int id;
@SerializedName(Constant.JSON_TITLE)
private String title;
@SerializedName(Constant.JSON_BODY)
private String body;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

}